# Why is my loop not returning the right answer?

Tags: c++

I can't figure it out. What is wrong with my code? I am new to programming.

**Program required output:** Write a C++ program to find the maximum-occurring character in an array, using a loop.

**My code:**

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void FindMaxChar(char Word[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    char index = 0;
    int length = strlen(Word);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        index = Word[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (index == Word[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > max)
        {
            max = count;
            index = Word[i];
        }
    }
    cout << index << " is repeating " << max << " times.";
}

int main()
{
    char Word[100] = {0};
    cout << "Enter the Word = ";
    cin.get(Word,100);
    FindMaxChar(Word);
}
```

**My Output:**

```
Enter the Word = caaar
r is repeating 11 times.
```

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to learn how to [debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging is essential skill of any programmer and the sooner you learn it, the better.

Comment: As part of debugging, you should train yourself to focus on details. There are *two* things wrong in your output, suggesting the presence of two bugs. (The wrong letter is chosen and the count is not correct for any letter.) When there are two bugs, you should simplify your code so you can ask about one bug at a time (see also [mre]). In this case, I would have dropped the count and focused on finding the right letter for your Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @JaMiT in all fairness, if they'd fixed the letter bug, it STILL would've displayed the same incorrect letter they have in their output because of the count bug. I don't think it's ever as simple as "I'm outputting two variables that are wrong, so there must be exactly one bug for each."

Comment: @scohe001 You are correct that sometimes bugs are intertwined. However, focusing on one symptom at a time can make it easier to find the cause. If fixing one happens to fix both, then so much the better. (If not, at least progress has been made.)

Answer (score 2):

You never reset `count` each loop. So you continue incrementing it but never clear it.

Add `count = 0` to the beginning of the outer for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    count = 0; // Reset counter
```

You're also trying to use `index` for two different purposes. You're both using it to store the current character you're looking at (not an index, kind of confusing that you named it like that), AND the character you've seen the most (still not an index, also confusing).

Instead, you need another variable here.

---

Also note that if you declare `Word` as `char Word[100]`, it can only hold a c-string of length 99 (to leave room for the null character). So your cin should actually be:

```
cin.get(Word, 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great people of this community.
I am able to find my error and corrected it.

**Correct Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void FindMaxChar(char Word[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    char index = 0;
    char final = 0;
    int length = strlen(Word);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        index = Word[i];
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (index == Word[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > max)
        {
            max = count;
            final = index;
        }
    }
    cout << final << " is repeating " << max << " times.";
}

int main()
{
    char Word[100] = {0};
    cout << "Enter the Word = ";
    cin.get(Word,99);
    FindMaxChar(Word);
}
```